# What's the difference between Breeze and BLAS when doing dot product of two vectors

Tags: apache-spark, breeze

Both Breeze and BlAS provides API to calculate dot product of two vectors

For BLAS, it is:

```
BLAS.ddot(int n, double[] dx, int incx, double[] dy, int incy);
```

For Breeze, it is:
    `DenseVector.dot`

I would ask what't the difference between them? Which one should I choose to use? I ask so because when I read the Spark MLLib code,  it looks that spark chooses BLAS to do vector calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, a BLAS library makes use of lower level functionalities of your machines, which can be highly optimized, depending on your configuration.
Breeze, on the other hand, is built as a general optimizer for linear algebra operations on Scala.

As both have different implementations (one big thing of Breeze is to utilize vector-only representations), you should use whatever is more fitting to your usecase.